# How can I delete a node within a XML file by using vbscript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, scripting, msxml, xmldom

I want to remove `<P_ID>` & `<P_Name>` nodes from every `<product>` node.

Here is what the XML looks like:

```xml
<products>
 <product>
     <P_ID><![CDATA[4]]></P_ID>
     <Item_T><![CDATA[Pt]]></Item_T>
     <P_Name><![CDATA[5]]></P_Name>
  </product>
  <product>
     <P_ID><![CDATA[4]]></P_ID>
     <Item_T><![CDATA[Pt]]></Item_T>
     <P_Name><![CDATA[5]]></P_Name>
  </product>
  <product>
     <P_ID><![CDATA[4]]></P_ID>
     <Item_T><![CDATA[Pt]]></Item_T>
     <P_Name><![CDATA[5]]></P_Name>
  </product>
  <product>
     <P_ID><![CDATA[4]]></P_ID>
     <Item_T><![CDATA[Pt]]></Item_T>
     <P_Name><![CDATA[5]]></P_Name>
  </product>
</products>
```

There are thousands of those product nodes.

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = Wscript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
objXMLDoc.async = False 

Dim XMLFile
XMLFile = "products.xml"
objXMLDoc.load(XMLFile) 
Set nodes = objXMLDoc.selectNodes("products/product/P_ID")
For Each node In nodes
  objXMLDoc.documentElement.remove
Next

objXMLDoc.Save(XMLFile)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference from the root node in your XPath string by prepending a slash. Then from the parent node you can call the `removeChild()` method passing the node to remove, like this...

```vb
Set nodes = objXMLDoc.selectNodes("/products/product/P_ID | " & _
                                  "/products/product/P_Name")
For Each node In nodes
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
Next
```

Comment: it says the parameter node is not a child of this node.

Comment: Yes sorry, we need to go back up to the parent, then call `removeChild()`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Try updated answer above. I've also updated the xpath to include both sets of nodes you want to remove. I've also tested it myself this time ;-)

Comment: No problemo. I should have tested first before answering the first time ;) Can you mark as the answer please.